# Expand numpy array dimensions to a given shape

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to reshape an array into a certain shape padding missing dimensions?

Let's say, we have an array `x`

```
x = np.arange(10)
```

Now we want to reshape it to `(1, 1, 1, 10, 1)`. We can do:

```
x = x.reshape((1, 1, 1, 10, 1))
```

or

```
x = x[None, None, None, x.shape[0], None]
```

But if the number and position of padding dimensions vary, this becomes quite inconvenient. 
Is there a better way?

Comment: A little more programatic way could be `x = x.reshape(num_pre * [1] + [x.shape[0]] + num_post * [1])`. Where in this case `num_pre = 3` and `num_post = 1`. Not sure if this is more convenient though.

Comment: It's not really clear how you get this shape, since that will drive the answer. For example is is padding on each side? Is it a set of axis indices? In general, you will use `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the new shape programatically:

```
pre_pad, post_pad = 5,2
new_shape = tuple([1]*pre_pad) + x.shape + tuple([1]*post_pad)

y = x.reshape(new_shape)

print(y.shape)
# (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), which gives you a lot of control:

```py
x = np.arange(10)

new_shape = np.pad([x.shape[0]],       # the thing to pad, in this case, [10]
                   (3,1),              # padding on (left, right)
                   'constant',    
                   constant_values=1)  # could specify L/R instead, e.g. (2,3)

y = x.reshape(new_shape)
y.shape
# (1, 1, 1, 10, 1)
```